# how to share a list between processes in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have two different node processes that run from the same file. I would like to seperate them into two different files. However, they share a list that looks like this.

```
var sensorUpdates = {};

setLastUpdate = function(monitor){
    sensorUpdates[monitor] = moment();
}

checkLastUpdate = function(monitor){
   if (sensorUpdates[monitor]) {
       ago = moment().unix() - sensorUpdates[monitor].unix()
       logmsg = "found " + monitor + " last update at " + 
       sensorUpdates[monitor].format('h:mm:ss') + ' ' + ago + ' seconds ago';
    //console.log(logmsg);
    return ago;
    } else {
        setLastUpdate(monitor);
        return 0;
    }
}
```

is there a way I can instantiate a list from one process and access it from another? Is this possible regardless of how many processes share this list? Simplest way I think to achieve this would be some sort of persistance, but i dont want to commit the resources necessary for database lookups because I dont think this would be fast enough

Comment: if `sensorUpdates` is global (which it appears to be), it can be initialized in either file and it will be in scope for both functions

Comment: does this include situations where they are run from different processes? like if i run node app/collect_sensors.js  and i run node app/process_sensors.js . they will share the object?

Comment: probably not - can you refactor your functions to make `sensorUpdates` a parameter?

Comment: You mean like an argument? That would still require starting one from the other, right? I would like to be able to run them separately. I thought perhaps I could set it up as a simple server but that is kinda more overhead for this. Thanks